# is fstream (or any other i/o function) able to ignore until a string

Tags: c++, string, animation, fstream

I'm working on a game engine for my intermediate c++ class's semester project using sfml.
Currently I'm trying to overcome a problem of reading in animation states from a organized data file.

My problem is I don't know if there is a way to use fstream.ignore() or a comparable function to ignore until a string rather than a character. I can accomplish what i need to with characters but it would be much cleaner and flex-able with strings.

I'm trying to make an automated class member function that will read in all relevant animations from an object from a data file.

Heres a sample of the function im tring to make.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Sprite.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Drawable.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
void animationInitialization();
int main()
{
.
.
animationInitialization();
.
}
    void animationInitialization()
    {

        sf::Texture objectTexture;
        sf::Sprite objectSprite;
        std::map<std::string, std::vector<sf::IntRect>> object; // map of a string and a vector of sprite sheet co-ordinates
        int frames, width, height, yPos;
        std::string objectAction;
        std::string objectName = "<DUCK>";
        std::string objectPreface = "duck.";
        std::string objectSpriteSheet;  
        std::string intTemp;
        std::fstream readin("scripts/animations.ini");


        readin.ignore(10000, objectName);// ignores until the section containing the proper animation is found
        readin.ignore(256, objectPreface + "File="); // ignores until the filename
        std::getline(readin, objectSpriteSheet); // reads in the sprite sheet filename

        while(!readin.eof())
        {
        // reads in the data
            readin.ignore(256, objectPreface + "action=");
            std::getline(readin, objectAction);
            readin.ignore(256, objectPreface + "width=");
            std::getline(readin, intTemp);
            width = atoi(intTemp.c_str());
            readin.ignore(256, objectPreface + "height=");
            std::getline(readin, intTemp);
            height = atoi(intTemp.c_str());
            readin.ignore(256, objectPreface + "Ylocation=");
            std::getline(readin, intTemp);
            yPos = atoi(intTemp.c_str());
            readin.ignore(256, objectPreface + "frames=");
            std::getline(readin, intTemp);
            frames = atoi(intTemp.c_str());

            // maps the animation locations
            for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++)
            {
                object[objectAction + " right"].push_back (IntRect(i*width, yPos, width, height));
                object[objectAction + " left"].push_back (IntRect(i*width+width, yPos, -width, height));
            }//end for
        }// end while

        // loads the sprite and texture
        objectTexture.loadFromFile(objectSpriteSheet);
        objectSprite.setTexture(objectTexture);

    } //end animationInitialization()
```

file it is reading: scripts/animations.ini

```
other animation stuff
blaaa
blaaa
bla
...
...
...
<DUCK> // want to find this first
duck.File=assets/DuckAnims.png
    duck.action=walk //action provides the map index
        duck.width=53
        duck.height=65
        duck.Ylocation=131
        duck.frames=7
    duck.action=jump
        duck.width=46
        duck.height=65
        duck.Ylocation=0
        duck.frames=5
    duck.action=punch
        duck.width=51
        duck.height=65
        duck.Ylocation=196
        duck.frames=9
    duck.action=kick
        duck.width=60
        duck.height=65
        duck.Ylocation=66
        duck.frames=3
more stuff for other anims
...
...
eof
```

Comment: I don't think so, but if you're concerned about clean code, you could simply wrap it into some function. Personally I'd suggest to use a well defined file format such as JSON or similar. That way you don't have to manually parse things.

Comment: Thanks, I found a way to parse it, but ill look into JSON.